# Javascript queries takes too long to execute in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, robo3t

I have two collection "Sample" and "Test" which is 300mb and 4GB respectively. When I tried to query the two collection in a single query I used Javascript. But it takes very long time to execute. How to increase the speed of the query? Below is the query.

```
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(x) {
  if (x.a == null) {
    print(x)
  } else if (x.a != null) {
    db.sample.find({}).forEach(function(y) {
      if (y._id == x._id && y.c == true) {
        print(x)
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Also will this query make use of Single indexe which is created on "c" and "a" fields.

Comment: You souldn't do query like this. Could you provide more informations on what you are trying to achieve (sample doc from your collections, expected results...)

Comment: The above query is just a structure. The document contains many fields. My expected output is I need to print the documents in "test" collection whose value is null. If it is not null, then check the document from "Sample" collection which has same _id as "test" collection _id and also check if "c" field is true. If it satisfy this condition it should print that document from "test" collection.